# How to optimially get records from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The key part of this question is 'Optimally' meaning the fastest return time. I have a few tables that have information I want pieces of. I'm not having any trouble writing the query itself, just on trying to determine what the fastest way to get the information would be.

- Audit (This is the primary table I want information from)
- Order (The rest are tables I want limited data from)
- Jobs
- Credits

The thing they share in common is an account and thus an AccountID. I have the AccountID that I'm looking for ahead of time. Unfortunately the audit table doesn't have a direct foreign key into the account table in question and thus to determine if the audit record belongs to my result set I'd have to join the audit table and the subsequent 3 tables one at a time to check if the audit record relates to my AccountID.

For example

```
Select a.* from [Audits] a JOIN [Orders] o ON a.RecordID = o.OrderID
where a.RecordType = 'Order' and o.AccountID = @AccountID
union
select a.* from [Audits] a JOIN [Jobs] j on a.RecordID = j.JobID
where a.RecordType = 'Job' and j.AccountID = @AccountID
...
```

I intend to do a fetch next on the first subset of data and then fill in the information from the secondary tables so that I'm doing a limited hit initially. I see this as a two part issue, first the fastest way to find the AuditID's that belong to my subset and second the fastest way to fill in the missing data. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I've come up with a solution for now, but I'd be interested in knowing if there are any simple ways to optimize it so I'm going to post it here in hopes it helps further clarify the problem. If you notice syntax errors please just ignore them, I'm trying to remove as much of the unnecessary information as possible.

```
Create Table #AuditTemp (columns)
Insert into #AuditTemp a.*, null as [Extra1], null as [Extra2] ...
From [Audits] a 
Left Join [Orders] o ON a.RecordID = o.OrderID
Left Join [Jobs] j ON a.RecordID = j.JobID
Left Join [Credits] c ON a.RecordID = c.CreditID
Where o.AccountID = @AccountID or j.AccountID = @AccountID ...
Order By Time desc
OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

Update #AuditTemp Set [Extra1] = o.[Column1] ...
From [Orders] Where o.AccountID = @AccountID and #AuditTemp.RecordID = o.OrderID 
...
```

So I get the 20 records that I need and then fill them in one at a time if they match up.

Comment: Let me see if I get it right: the `RecordID` field from the `Audit` table can be either an Order, a Job or a Credit, and the only thing they share in common is the `AccountID` field?

Comment: That looks... fun.  The one thing that comes to mind is using `union all` instead of `union`. That will skip the extra sort and de-duplication from `union`.

Comment: What version & edition of sql server are you using? `select @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0

Comment: @JoshPart for simplicity's sake you can assume you are correct that the only field they share in common is the AccountID. The RecordID is a FK into the Order, Job, or Credit tables and RecordType will tell you which one of those it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is something you have to do constantly, I'll suggets creating a `view` from your secondary tables, and use it to join your `Audit` table with your secondary tables.

```
CreateView [dbo].[SecondaryTables]
AS
SELECT OrderID AS RecordID, 'Order' AS RecordType, AccountID
FROM [Orders]
UNION
SELECT JobID AS RecordID, 'Job' AS RecordType, AccountID
FROM [Jobs]
UNION
SELECT CreditID AS RecordID, 'Credit' AS RecordType, AccountID
FROM [Credits]
```

Then you can use this view to join all the data you need

```
SELECT [all your required fields]
FROM [SecondaryTables] vw
INNER JOIN [Audit] au
ON vw.RecordID = au.RecordID AND vw.RecordType = au.RecordType
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Orders] od
ON vw.RecordID = od.OrderID AND vw.RecordType = 'Order'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Jobs] jo
ON vw.RecordID = jo.JobID AND vw.RecordType = 'Job'
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Credits] cr
ON vw.RecordID = cr.CreditID AND vw.RecordType = 'Credit'
WHERE vw.AccountID = @AccountID
```

If you expect results from all the tables (all your results will always include data from the 3 tables), you can change the `LEFT OUTER` to `INNER` to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is look at the execution plan for the query.  A possible alternative would be as shown below.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM [Audits] A

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT OrderID AS RecordID FROM [Orders] WHERE AccountID = @AccountID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT JobID AS RecordID FROM [Jobs] WHERE AccountID = @AccountID
) AS DT
ON A.RecordID = DT.RecordID
WHERE A.RecordType IN ('Order','Job')
```

Another alternative is to shift the UNION ALL query into a common table expression.

The SQL Server optimiser is pretty good these days.  It is easy to find the query that costs the least but that is not quite the same thing as the fastest.

If you typically have very few orders or jobs for an account then you will be joining to very few records and joining only once rather than twice as in the original.

Consider the selectivity of the RecordType in the [audits] table.  If Order and Job comprises of the majority of your records then there is little benefit in adding an index against RecordType.  Presumably Order and Jobs have an index against AccountID?

Consider being explicit in the schema for your tables.  dbo.Audits, Sales.orders etc.  It is just one less thing for the query engine to have to compare at run time.

Performance testing on SQL Server can be a bit of a pain in a shared environment.  I find using SQL Profiler gives a good indication as to what is going on both for my query and whatever else is running at the time, plus it will give you all the timings you want.

If you are testing when the server is quiet remember the DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS will flush out the buffer cache after each run so you can get a definite view on how the query will perform from cold.

If your production box is a different spec to your test box then you are on a hiding to nothing.  A multi-core server with huge amounts of RAM and shared storage is going to perform differently to a typical DEV workstation particularly if you are running multiple tasks on it at the same time.